# Spying on function checking when testing React component onClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, jestjs, enzyme

I have a Parent and a child component.

Parent Component:

```
const ParentComponent = () => {

    const click_button = (role) => {
        document.getElementById(role).innerHTML = role;
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <ChildButton id= 'button_child' name='button_1' onClick={() => {
                click_button('role_1')
            }}/>
            <div>
                <p id="role_1"/>
                <p id="role_2"/>
                <p id="role_3"/>
            </div>
        </div>

    )

}

export default ParentComponent;
```

Child Component

```
import React from 'react';

const ChildButton = (props) => {

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <button onClick={props.onClick}>{props.name}</button>
        </React.Fragment>
    )
}

export default ChildButton;
```

One of the Tests for `ParentComponent`:

```
    it('buttons should render correctly', () => {
        const wrapper shallow(<ParentComponent/>);
        const instance = wrapper.instance();
        jest.spyOn(instance, 'click_button');
        expect(instance.click_button).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(0);
        wrapper.find('#button_child').simulate('click');
        expect(instance.click_button).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    });
```

My application using jest and enzyme for testing. The on click functionality in the example needs to be tested in the ParentComponent. However, when I attempt to access the button the test fails and this is to the fact that the button is in the `childButton` component.

So basically the quest is how do I test the `click_button` function in the `ParentComponent`?

The example above instance is null, enzyme documentation says this will be the case.  Now the only way I've seen individuals get round this is by 'watching' for a console log, which seems a bit hacky to me?

I am trying to stick with Enzyme and Jest as that is what my unit tests are written in and I'm hoping my integration testing can follow suit.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you are "integration" testing the parent and child together, why *shallow* render it? And you shouldn't be spying on anything - the expectation for the test should be that the relevant element content is updated.

Comment: *"I wish to know that the click_button function has been called"* - no, you don't. That might make sense when testing Child in isolation, where you check that the function passed as a prop is called, but when testing Parent and Child together you want to check that Parent *implements the right behaviour*. `click_button` is an implementation detail, it's not even accessible outside the function.

Comment: Ok I'm going about this the wrong way. How should I test click_button  exactly ? Thanks

Comment: Again, test the *behaviour*. When it’s clicked the DOM should be updated (although that’s not a React way of doing it), so test for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test the behavior of the components rather than the implementation details. Test parent and child components together using the `mount()` function of `enzyme`. React functional components have no instances, but class components have instances.

E.g.

`parent.jsx`:

```
import ChildButton from './child';

const ParentComponent = () => {
  const click_button = (role) => {
    document.getElementById(role).innerHTML = role;
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <ChildButton
        id="button_child"
        name="button_1"
        onClick={() => {
          click_button('role_1');
        }}
      />
      <div>
        <p id="role_1" />
        <p id="role_2" />
        <p id="role_3" />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ParentComponent;
```

`child.jsx`:

```
import React from 'react';

const ChildButton = (props) => {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <button onClick={props.onClick}>{props.name}</button>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default ChildButton;
```

`parent.test.jsx`:

```
import React from 'react';
import ParentComponent from './parent';
import { mount } from 'enzyme';

describe('66698493', () => {
  beforeAll(() => {
    const div = document.createElement('div');
    div.setAttribute('id', 'container');
    document.body.appendChild(div);
  });
  it('should change the inner HTML', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(<ParentComponent />, { attachTo: document.getElementById('container') });
    expect(document.getElementById('role_1').innerHTML).toEqual('');
    wrapper.find('button').simulate('click');
    expect(document.getElementById('role_1').innerHTML).toEqual('role_1');
  });
});
```

test result:

```
 PASS  examples/66698493/parent.test.jsx
  66698493
    ✓ should change the inner HTML (46 ms)

------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File        | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files   |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 child.jsx  |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 parent.jsx |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        6.067 s
```

`jest.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  preset: 'ts-jest/presets/js-with-ts',
  testEnvironment: 'enzyme',
  setupFilesAfterEnv: [
    'jest-enzyme',
  ],
  setupFiles: ['./jest.setup.js'],
  testEnvironmentOptions: {
    enzymeAdapter: 'react16',
  },
};
```

Comment: Thanks very comprehensive answer! All makes sense. Have a super day.